# SQL 2005 - two tables Join on some id,

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Let's say I have 2 tables. I want join them so that for every account I get 1 row where the account's information is there PLUS the primaryContact's information appended to the table.
Is this possible? ID's are unique keys.

**ACCOUNT TABLE**

```
 accountid    |    name    |    income    |    primaryContact  

 123456789     Jack Johnson    120,000      Jill Johnson
```

**CONTACT TABLE**

```
parentAccountid    |contactid    |    name    |    street        |    city    |    state    |    Country

 123456789           13459284      Jill Johnson    1355 Fir street  Yorba         Washington      USA
```

**RESULT TABLE**

```
  accountid    |    name    |    income    |    primaryContact    |    street    |    city    |    state    |    country 

 123456789     Jack Johnson    120,000      Jill Johnson           1355 Fir street   Yorba           Washington      USA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.accountid     ,
       a.name          ,
       a.income        ,
       a.primaryContact,
       c.street        ,
       c.city          ,
       c.state         ,
       c.country
FROM   account a
       JOIN contact c
       ON     a.accountid      = c.parentAccountid
       AND    a.primaryContact = c.name
```

Comment: There's no `CONTACT.primarycontact` column ;)

Comment: So if wanted to include those accounts without a primaryContact (null) then I do a left outer join? Thanks.

Comment: @Ehsan - Yes. By the way have you considered adding a `contactid` column to account rather than name. Being numeric it might be a bit quicker for joins also if people change their name (e.g. get married) there is less to update.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
   SELECT a.accountid,
          a.name,
          a.income,
          a.primaryContact,
          c.street,
          c.city,
          c.state,
          c.country
     FROM ACCOUNT a
LEFT JOIN CONTACT c ON c.parentaccountid = a.accountid
                   AND c.name = a.primarycontact
```

This will show you all the accounts.  If there's a primary contact, the values will be populated--otherwise the references to the `CONTACT` table will be NULL.  If you don't want this behavior, omit the "LEFT" from the query:

```
   SELECT a.accountid,
          a.name,
          a.income,
          a.primaryContact,
          c.street,
          c.city,
          c.state,
          c.country
     FROM ACCOUNT a
     JOIN CONTACT c ON c.parentaccountid = a.accountid
                   AND c.name = a.primarycontact
```

[See this link for a visual representation of the different JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)...

Comment: Thanks! You're correct, I should've been more specific. forgot about those nulls.